# React + Material Design Lite - How to close navigation drawer when menu link is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, react-router

so I am unsure of how to best go about closing the MDL drawer when a link is clicked inside the drawer. From similar questions I have gathered you simply need to remove the `is-active` class from both the div with a class of `mdl-layout__obfuscator`, and the div with a class of `mdl-layout__drawer`.

What is the best way to go about this in React? I am not using [React-MDL](https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/) by the way, I am using the CDN version if that matters or helps...

Sorry I am new to both React and MDL.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, we can use react state to handle the show/hide the component. But in this case, we cannot do as we dont have access to have state in react-mdl inbuilt component. So i would suggest to manipulate the react-mdl component.

What manipulate DOM? :O Really?

Yes. We are not doing DOM manipulation for our code, we are just manipulating react-mdl so I think this should not be a issue.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
hideToggle() {
    var selectorId = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout');
    selectorId.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
}

render() {
    return (
        <Navigation>
            <Link to={routes.XXX} onClick={() => this.hideToggle()}> XXX</Link>
        </Navigation>

    );
}
```

This should solve your issue.

Ref: [Github source](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1246)

Thank you.